# Give an example of a metric space that has this condition.

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone give a set $X$ and two metrics $d,d'$ on $X$ such that $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ are homeomorphic, but $f:X\to X$ given by $f(x)=x$ is not uniformly continuous?

I've got this:

If $d'(f(x),f(y))<\delta \Rightarrow (x^{2}+xy+y^{2})d(x,y)<\delta \Rightarrow (x^{2}+xy+y^{2})d(f(x),f(y))<\delta $

but I don't know how to conclude or how this is a contradiction.

Comment: Consider that $(-1,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, create a matric on $(-1,1)$ which is unbounded.

Comment: It has to be the same space :)

Comment: I know, but you can "pull back" the metric on $\mathbb R$ to get a metric on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: I am back in the discussion, so what do you mean by pullback ? (the pullback of differential forms)

Comment: If you have a one-to-one function $f:X\to Y$, and $(Y,d)$ is a metric space, you can pull it back to a metric $d'$ on $X$ by defining $d'(x_1,x_2)=d(f(x_1),f(x_2))$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this please, is because I don't understand how could this help to answer the question? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\mathbb R$, $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d'(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|$. Then $$d'(f(x),f(y))=|x^3-y^3|=(x^2+xy+y^2)d(x,y).$$
Can you see why in this case $f$ is not uniformly continuous?

EDIT: Here is the reasoning. Fix $\epsilon>0$. We show that for every $\delta>0$, there exist $x,y\in\mathbb R$ with $d(x,y)<\delta$ but $d'(f(x),f(y))\ge\epsilon$, which would imply $f$ is not uniformly continuous. (We in fact only need to show this for a particular value of $\epsilon$, but in this example any will do.) We may as well fix $y=x+\frac\delta2$, since now $d(x,y)<\delta$ regardless of the value of $x$, and play around with $x$ to see how we can reach our conclusion. Indeed,
$$d'(f(x),f(y))=(x^2+xy+y^2)d(x,y)=(x^2+x(x+\tfrac\delta2)+(x+\tfrac\delta2)^2)\tfrac\delta2\\
=\frac{3x^2\delta}2+\frac{3x\delta^2}4+\frac{\delta^3}8\to\infty\quad\text{as }x\to\infty,$$
so it is clear that by choosing $x$ sufficiently large we have our desired pair $x,y$. In practice, you don't really need to do all this working, just observe that $x^2+xy+y^2$ is not bounded for pairs $x,y$ with $d(x,y)<\delta$.

Comment: Give me a while becausw here is a little bit late, so can I give you the answer tomorrow ? Jajajajajajajaj

Comment: I am back :), just give some minutes to check your answer right?

Comment: How do you prove the triangle inequality of the second metric?

Comment: Oh I think the triangle inequality is satisfied because $d'(x,y)=d(x^{3},y^{3})$ right?

Comment: I have edited my post :) Can you check it please?

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully it is clear now.